# November 2016 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow's [8th moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: deceze] [image: Aaron Hall] [image: Bhargav Rao]

They've joined [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6488198410665984/0).

Comment: Congratulations to deceze, AaronHall and BhargavRao. Well done and good luck with your new task!

Comment: Good choices.  One out of three ain't bad.  And if you think you're the one I voted for, you're wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind, losers, that mods step down and runners up may be asked to step in.  So don't start cursing everybody out just yet :)

Comment: Congrats, guys! You've proven unbeatable :D Good luck, and stay sane!

Comment: Welcome aboard, and congratulations!

Comment: I can't help noticing the revenge downvotes on this post.  I'm guessing their candidates didn't win.

Comment: Before everyone on the planet weighs in with their congratulations and this comment thread has to be purged... I'll just say on their behalf "Welcome to the official Stack Overflow Janitorial Team™.  It's worth every penny of the pay you'll receive."

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel honoured to be on board. Except for you, @Will, since you didn't vote for me. ;)

Comment: Congrats. Now get to work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey with your comment in mind I'm voting to close this question because "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community."

Comment: Congratulations! It's a shame there aren't any good synonyms for that word!

Comment: Congratulations! At least one of my fav candidates joined in! Happy moderating for you all, choice wasn't easy.

Comment: Thanks to all those who voted in the elections. I'll try to be a good moderator :)

Comment: I'm rather shocked that a candidate who didn't bother giving any reasons for wanting to be a mod, and the only one who didn't reply to the questionnaire, made it to round 8 of 11. But I suppose it's the year for surprising votes, hmm?

Comment: @BhargavRao You've got a good nose, do you? (I <3 Pink Floyd album covers ;) )

Comment: @Bhargav, you wear the diamond quite naturally :]

Comment: Now we just wait for the flairs to update to show the diamonds…

Comment: Is now the time to start moderating the site?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: 2 out of 3 for me. That's pretty good. Congrats to the new mods. And: keep on trying to the others! Maybe next year.

Comment: Congratulations! It seems the choice was great and to the point! Go-go-go, we already are checking the melting moderation queues ;) ! Good luck!

Comment: @Farside I'm not so sure that starting out into business overly quick is a good idea. Give them the time to accommodate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: 100 days?

Comment: @Will, may I vote for you, when there will be troll-elections on StackOverflow? I'd give you the first place for keeping the fun, and the other people, who vote for your first comments! :)

Comment: @Olaf Shudder!!

Comment: @πάντα, that whole point is moot -- of course, on Stack Overflow, newly elected moderators are trained and operational in six to eight weeks.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't dissent. 6 - 8 weeks sounds reasonable.

Comment: Yes! 6-8 weeks? Bah! 1 week boot-camp.

Comment: There's a one week training for this gig?  How did I miss that memo?

Comment: @Olaf My plantz would complain. 18 hours of daylight is already hard to bear :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey You know "Full Metal Jacket", don't you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What's trhe antonym of "daylight"? Not sure about your place, but we have currently 18h nightdark here:-P

Comment: @Olaf _""Full Metal Jacket"_ Sure I do. It ended up _bloody_ :P ...

Comment: @Olaf It's just a question of choosing the right illumination technology. Ever heard of daylight spectrum illuminants? My fish depend their lives on that.

Comment: @πάντα, tough luck. They should have evolved better.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Who's your local _vitamine D_ dealer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Me too. But commonly "daylight" refers to that big fusion reactor in the sky some people think is very far away.

Comment: I love this Rube Goldberg voting: a method called "Meek STV", 815 ballots, 5 parameters, intimidating terms like "Droop Threshold Formula" and "Backwards Weak Tie Breaking", 11 rounds and graphs, each with yellow, green and red bars, vote transferring, exhausted votes, surplus votes, keep factors calculated to the sixth decimal digit... And in the end the result would have been the same if we had simply taken the 3 most voted! :-P

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Not to mention all the skepticism expressed about their contributions and qualifications by existing mods and prominent community members. But hey, voting worked out in the end.

Comment: I've got two of three votes right. Do I win something?

Comment: @FabioTurati: The best part is [the wastage of significant votes through misuse of STV](//politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/in-single-transferable-vote-elections-how-bad-is-it-to-have-a-lot-of-wasted-vot). But hey, I got 2/3 of my preferred candidates, so I'm not *too* unhappy.

Comment: @FabioTurati On the other hand, if there were only 2 open positions, then Bhargav Rao would be one of two winners despite being 3rd in the count of first-place votes.

Comment: @BhargavRao Congrats! Good to see a mod from Namma Bengaluru

Comment: I don't get OpaVote? What are these 11 rounds from? Who defines the Threshold? What is the difference in using top 3 raw votes? [And why is the difference worth so much money?](http://www.opavote.com/pricing)

Comment: @zaq Indeed, but please don't take my comment too seriously. I've put a `:-P` at the end, don't miss it!

Comment: Congrats for 2 of 3 (@Aaron Hall & @BhargavRao). Remember that being diamond have more responsibility to everyone, use your "magical" powers wisely.

Comment: Well @FabioTurati, we need a system that it's a fair as it's mathematically possible https://vimeo.com/190024419

Comment: congrats @deceze for your winning. Hope this will be a milestone for three of you contribute a lot to community & inspiring us as well. Bravo =)

Comment: @BhargavRao and Deceze Congrats! I voted for you guys.. just saying :)

Comment: Congratulations to our new Moderators (i voted for Bhargav)... :-)

Comment: Congrats to all, specially proud of @BhargavRao. My first choice is you. You are the only person to become the moderator within two year  in SO, Very good lifetime achievement..

Comment: Congrats to all the winners and @Bhargav Rao

Comment: Yippie, voted for you three. Congratulations everyone ^_^

Comment: They are exactly the 3 ones on whom I voted :)

Comment: My all prediction is perfect. I have voted for this 3 guys only with the same priority. 
Congratulations @BhargavRao  ,deceze and Aaron Hall

Comment: Who the heck is voting to close this post as unclear? I mean cmon

Comment: We only have 22 moderators? :O

Comment: @Josh I over trusted community ;) - congrats to winners, well deserved

Comment: @CodeAndSecure Same here. I was even surprised about the order.

Comment: None of the folks I've voted for? That's some luck right there!

Comment: I don't think there's a clear answer to that, @Magisch.

Comment: Congratulations to deceze, AaronHall and BhargavRao. Great to see growing stackoverflow community, as developer life without stackoverflow is zero.Members helping each other and contributing to each others growth.Three cheers!! for you 3 this is result of great work till now you done.

Comment: With respect to all who wrote *congratulations,* I think it's just as appropriate to write *thanks.* **Thanks** to you new mods for taking on this task. **Thanks** to the others who ran. You gave the community the chance to make real choices about our governance, from among excellent candidates.

Comment: Nice to see that ALL my 3 favourites won. On the previous one, only one of my candidates passed (if I remember well).

Comment: Congrats to our new moderator ( i voted for @BhargavRao )

Comment: Just taking the three people with the highest vote count would've been too easy I guess...especially since the result would've been the same.

Comment: you said 3 mods, but you posted  5 mods photos , how is this possible ?

Answer (score 316):

Welcome, new moderators!

Your shovels and forks await you, please start shovelling at your earliest convenience:

[image: pile of dirt with fork]

Comment: That pile is made of the wrong material...

Comment: …who shovels dirt with a fork?

Comment: @stephen sssshhh... Don't ruin the fun we have with the new recruits :-P

Comment: @EdCottrell: I was tempted to use [this image](http://www.perou.co.uk/photos/2085.jpg) but wanted the tool to be present too..

Comment: @StephenLeppik: sometimes, that's what it feels like around here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now, that's more like it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik That's not dirt, it's compost mulch, and a fork is the right tool for the job; that's what I use.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Bringing some real-life experience in here — a few months ago I went to get some mulch from the city recycling plant, where they have gigantic mound of decomposing mulch and anyone who wants it can go get some for free. I got around 3 truckloads full, and it was oddly satisfying to use a fork for getting it — I implore you to try it some time — it may change your life (what does this have to do with the election, you may ask? This shows the new moderators that although they feel they might not be able to do something they can indeed do it if they use the tools at their disposal)

Comment: @Jojodmo Re "they can indeed do it if they use the tools at their disposal": Yes, pitch softly and drive a big truck.

Comment: As long as the pitchforks are reserved only for users chasing the moderators of course.

Comment: Is this already part of the hazing, or is that still coming?

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/63UlBsdElsY/hqdefault.jpg imo

Comment: Congratulations ... having actually shoveled one of these piles, I mostly remember it collapsing and always seeming larger at the end of the day!

Comment: @rfornal: that's a surprisingly accurate description of the SO flag queue!

Comment: @StephenLeppik - Pig Farmers.

Comment: Congrats. Gotta good work

Comment: congratulations buddy

Comment: when someone do something fishy , don't forget somebody is [watching](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/10/16/16/2D7AE7AA00000578-3276063-image-a-33_1445008515671.jpg)

Comment: Congrats , you got work

Comment: @BillalBegueradj: please don't assume I'm here 24/7. Moderators are volunteers, and not "elected to answer and give me feedback"; we are elected to handle moderation tasks. Your comment was removed by another moderator, 5 years ago, as were other comments, in response to comment flags.

Answer (score 170):

My congratulations and best wishes goes out to our new moderators Aaron Hall, Bhargav Rao, and deceze! Thank you for stepping up to nominate yourselves this election, and also inspiring me to do the same. I commend the three of you for selflessly volunteering your time to take on this enormous responsibility, and believe you'll all do well as moderators.

Comment: And congrats to you on 4th place! Is the Bat-Signal installed yet for when they need to [call on you](http://i.imgur.com/DGzSZ8h.png)? ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Hope that you'll be called up too :)

Comment: @cerbrus you'll still see me in SOCVR of course

Comment: @BhargavRao congratulations! I'm glad my vote for you didn't go to waste :D

Comment: A very classy response from a classy individual. Quite obviously Australian. ;)

Comment: I'm confident you will make it, too one day. Just don't give up!

Comment: I voted for you :) good to see you made it to runner-up.

Comment: Commiserations Samuel, you were my only pick who missed out. Please try again next year so that I can get all three candidates.

Comment: I was really hoping you'd get elected. From what I can tell you're a well rounded guy that'd make a great moderator. if it still makes sense for you, please run next election :)

Comment: @Steven Wolfe: He's actually from Singapore, like me, but moved to Australia relatively recently. I'm pretty jelly to be honest - I grew up alongside their culture and have many close Aussie mates today so it's like a second home I've never been.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't want to draw attention to that, but you noticed anyway >.<

Comment: @Samuel Liew: Psh, [there's nothing to be ashamed of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXQO3.png)!

Comment: You were my first choice, and the only pick of mine not to be elected - fingers crossed for next time!

Comment: I hope you run again next year, if you don't get called up. I didn't expect much when I saw your nomination, but reading your responses, your questionnaire answers, and just how you've presented yourself since your nomination, I think you'd make an excellent mod. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Keep up your spirit. I noted you during this election, if no one else outstands you, you might very well become my first choice during next election!

Comment: You had my vote... better luck next time!

Comment: @Cerbrus is there a way for them to call on you?

Comment: @MarkYisri: Yes: If they need more moderators, the runner-ups will be contacted.

Comment: A big shout out to the three new mods and to all those that give their time and knowledge. You are all legends! Respect from California :)