# Is it normal to keep fun or chatty comments selectively on Meta?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, comment-flags

On Meta, sometimes, there are huge discussions in comments, which are personal, chatty, or just for keeping the fun, rather than being constructive in relation to specific topic/question/answer.

I'm wondering, is it higher tolerance on some topics (the latest example could be [Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338289/november-2016-community-moderator-election-results)) where chatty comments are not supposed to be flagged, or how it is regulated on Meta.

I clearly understand, that discussion/comments are unessential part of Meta, as it's stated in the model itself:

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow

But sometimes these "comments entites" are not bringing any real iformational value to community. How to cross this thin line, and when to **flag** a comment and when it's exceptional?
Wouldn't themed chats be better for the actual chatting, instead of meaningless comments?

Comment: We hate fun >|( !!!!

Comment: Thanks for a good example ^^^. These I actually meant, @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: _@Fanside_ I know! That's why I wrote it.

Comment: I think people don't flag comments as much on Meta because discussion is OK here. For the most part, even the silly comments are somewhat related to the discussion. I've never seen a comment thread where one user suddenly asked another user whether they decided to buy a boat or anything like that.

Comment: The existing Q+A engine is just grossly inadequate to have a meaningful discussion.  The back-and-forth that's essential to have a discussion happens in the comments, answers are but a soapbox.  It still sort-of works, good comments get upvoted so you can still filter out the noise.  Fwiw, one of the site founders (Jeff Atwood) moved on and created Discourse, designed to empower discussion.  That it did not come back to power meta is a shame.

Comment: YOU LEAVE OUR UNICORNS AND WAFFLES ALONE.

Comment: We all are humans, a positive sharing or meaningful discussion - is normal for a healthy community, but there were a lot of chatty peer-to-peer messages with mentions, which are frankly "too much" (which I honestly would **flag**). At the same time it probably would be expected to cheer up, congratulate, give some tips or improvements, or even to throw a friendly joke (but still to the point)...  Am, I right, @Will?! those are needed! =)

Comment: @Farside There isn't anything "meaningful" that could ever be contributed to that post, beyond what's in the question.  The whole post pretty much exists for the informal conversations to all take place there, so that it doesn't spill over into other questions.

Comment: They couldn't possibly be off topic comments if they're upvoted

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305932/not-constructive-flags-on-meta-comments-declined)? Or the other way round? Anyway, you got a warmer greeting.

Answer (score 39):

Yes, it's quite normal. Meta is sometimes, but not always and never exclusively, a Q&A site like all the others... But it also functions as a discussion board, a bug tracker, and occasionally just a place for blowing off steam.

We'll remove comments if they get *too* distracting, but generally use a lighter touch here than elsewhere.

Comment: I agree and I disagree. There is fine fun in waffles and unicorns, WHICH NO ONE SHOULD TOUCH (amirite Will?), but then there are legitimate issues with comments which draw a fine line between acceptable and trolling. Trolling has become more popular on meta because of these relaxed rules, and since it is supposed to be in the form of a quip, the trolling is very passive aggressive. Perhaps this has also led to a broken window effect where the same approaches bleed out into main as many users (especially unfamiliar ones) do not understand the disconnect or "lighter touch".

Comment: _"too distracting"_ - Please define.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Did you know that some rabbits can weigh up to 25 kg?

Comment: @GillBates No Bill I did not. But what do rabbits have to do with U-235 fission cross-section for thermal neutrons being 582.6 barn???

Comment: I would expect that "trolling" comments would also be removed on Meta, @Travis. A "lighter touch" doesn't mean "anything goes", it just means the rules are relaxed. And I don't know if you're trying to imply that anything "passive aggressive" is "trolling", but that certainly seems like a fallacy to me. Besides, the character limit and the inherent limitations of textual communication often conspire to make a comment seem far more passive aggressive than it was actually meant to be. For example, your comment delivering a sideways critique of certain Meta commentators.