# Disable close-votes for [featured] meta questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, featured-questions

Theoretically, it's possible to close [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (meta) questions. 
Usually, these questions are announcements made by staff / moderators.

The latest announcement, the [November 2016 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338289/november-2016-community-moderator-election-results), has gotten a close-vote as *"Unclear what you're asking"*.
Technically, that might be correct, but it's pretty silly to want to close that (or any) announcement.

Would it be an idea to disable close-votes on [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions?

It's (arguably) more user-friendly to block close-votes, than to allow them when they're going to be undone, any way.

Comment: On the one hand, this mirrors main-site functionality re bountied questions. On the other hand… this mirrors main-site functionality re bountied questions.

Comment: Let's just close vote that question, so we can go on a witch-hunt ...

Comment: What on Earth for?  Afraid that it isn't going to get re-opened or gets deleted?  Well, no.

Comment: Because it's arguably more user-friendly to block close-votes, than to allow them when they're going to be undone, any way, @HansPassant. Sure, it's not a massive issue. But I'd say it improves UX.

Answer (score 7):

Is the juice *really* worth the squeeze here?  My gut feeling tells me *no*.

There are *never* that many [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions active at any one given time.  Once that tag is removed, they're regarded as normal, regular posts - well, posts that don't appear in the "Featured" section on the sidebar - and are still open to them being closed, protected, or even deleted.

Given their temporal nature, and given the fact that a featured post isn't all that much more special than a non-featured post, I wouldn't think that implementing a system to prevent them from being closed would be worth the effort.

Comment: I'm curious how much effort it would be to implement this. Maybe a SO Dev with some spare time (heh) could plug it in in half an hour... Most of all, I'm curious what the community's opinion on this request is. So, instead of dismissing it as "Too much effort", I'm looking for responses like _"Good / Bad idea, because <...>"_. Still, thanks for your response.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Irrespective of the time you may think it'll take, I personally don't see that work having the level of impact you intend it to.  Besides, users like us would immediately correct some misguided group of five people who believed that closing a featured question was necessary.

Comment: I agree that a closure like that will be fixed in no time at all. I realize my previous comment may be a little blunt, that was not my intention. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the Question and Answer format of Stack Exchange sites *isn't really the right paradigm for announcements* that neither seek feedback nor have a clear answer. Most programmers believe in using the right tool for the right job. If the *wrong* tool (a Q&A site) is used for the wrong job (making community announcements), closevotes are a natural result.

Perhaps these community announcements need a different paradigm - perhaps a new kind of post, or a separate "Stack Overflow Announcements" or "Stack Overflow News" site that allows only comments, not answers, to be added to posts and that might not have voting features.

Comment: Some featured content does ask for feedback, which can either come in the way of answers to the original topic, or bugs opened as questions.  A separate site doesn't give us that flexibility.

Comment: @Makoto true. There is a difference, however, between a featured post whose primary purpose is seeking community feedback and a featured post whose primary purpose is making an announcement and any feedback received is secondary. The featured post linked by the OP is one of the second - it is an announcement, and a mod even posted about the possibility of deleting response comments. Consider it - it is announcing the results of an election. What are people supposed to do to "answer" it? Contest the results of the election? Post their approval of the democratic process? Call for a recount?

Comment: It's still a matter of semantics.  These sorts of announcement posts are *only* possible on Meta because the rules around discussion and *strict* Q&A are relaxed enough to allow these kinds of announcements.  Further to that, you have to take into consideration that ***every site on the network*** would need to have a separate site to include/incorporate their announcements, and that's a ***lot*** of overhead for a very, very little problem.